No-charge Drupal alternatives to Acquia's Site Studio
This is a general one. I would like to know better the spectrum of choices for Acquia Site Studio alternative in 2024.
The most important features from my perspective are:

ability to create many reusable visual web components relatively quickly (doesn't have to be low-code though)
possibility to configure how the components look just via UI
easy for content editing from UI
working well with standard Drupal's architecture (no not-flexible black-box thing inside my CMS)
works well with Drupal 9+

Thanks for any insights that you may have!

Software recommendations are off topic here I’m afraid, because there can’t be a “right” answer (important for Q+A). From personal experience though, there’s no free alternative to Site Studio out there in the wild

The closest you will get right now is DXPR or Blokkli. There is an upcoming initiative to improving Layout Builder in core for this, check the recent announcements.

This question has a list of well defined functional requirements that can certainly be parsed and evaluated empirically.  Let's adjust the title of the question to remove "Best" and reopen this?

Wow, very keen to hear about it @Kevin , thanks!

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says "Questions asking to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources" are off-topic.
